# Infinit loop with firebase and angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm having an infinit loop problem saving my data on firebase with
`this.db.collection('users').doc(this.useruid).update({Info: this.currentInfo})`

```
private currentInfo:string[];
private useruid: string;
...
constructor(private AngularAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db:AngularFirestore) { }

...

sendInfo(text:string){
    this.useruid = this.AngularAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
    this.db.collection('users').doc(this.useruid).snapshotChanges().subscribe(a=>{
      const data = a.payload.data() as {name:string, Info:string[]};
      data.Info.forEach(element => {
        this.currentInfo.push(element);
      });
      this.currentInfo.push(text);
      this.db.collection('users').doc(this.useruid).update({
        Info: this.currentInfo
      })...
    })
}
```

As an example, imagine I currently have as `currentInfo = ["a","b","c"]` and as `text = "d"`, after y run the method `sendInfo( )`,
i get a loop with: `["a","b","c","d","a","b","c","d","d","a","b","c","d","a","b","c","d","d","d"...]` and so on.

Comment: I removed the [tag:angularjs] tag as your question is about [tag:angular]

Comment: Since you have an actively listener to the document, and update it in that listener, the infinite loop is expected to me. What do you want the result to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a document based on its current value, [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions):

```
var userDocRef = collection('users').doc(this.useruid);

return db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
    return transaction.get(userDocRef).then(function(userDoc) {
        if (!userDoc.exists) {
            throw "Document does not exist!";
        }

        const data = userDoc.data() as {name:string, Info:string[]};
        data.Info.forEach(element => {
          this.currentInfo.push(element);
        });
        this.currentInfo.push(text);

        transaction.update(userDocRef, { Info: this.currentInfo });
    });
}).then(function() {
    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
});
```

In addition to preventing the infinite loop that you currently have, this also prevents multiple users from overwriting each other's results if they want to update the document at almost the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipe and first to get the values that you need and then update again.

```
sendInfo(text: string) {
    this.useruid = this.AngularAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
    this.db.collection('users').doc(this.useruid).valueChanges().pipe(first()).subscribe(a => {
        const data = a.payload.data() as {name:string, Info:string[]};
        data.Info.forEach(element => {
            this.currentInfo.push(element);
        });
        this.currentInfo.push(text);
    }
    this.db.collection('users').doc(this.useruid).update({
        Info: this.currentInfo
    })
}
```

The first method of rxjs is used to get the first value emitted by an observable. After that, it unsubscribes from the observable.

Comment: That's what I tried at first but it did not work correctly for my project, thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the problem that you face if you use this solution?